# Programmatically define Tasklist - ArgumentException 'HierarchyParentKeyColumnName'

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

I am trying to programmatically add a Tasklist with the new Timeline to my Solution. However it seems not be compatible with my ContentType.
The ContentType inherits from a Task but has to remove the Fields `PercentComplete`, `AssignedTo` and `Priority` and renames DueDate and StartDate. My Content Type looks like this:

```
<!--PercentComplete-->
<FieldRef ID="{d2311440-1ed6-46ea-b46d-daa643dc3886}" Hidden="TRUE" />
<!--AssignedTo-->
<FieldRef ID="{53101f38-dd2e-458c-b245-0c236cc13d1a}" Hidden="TRUE" />
<!--PreviouslyAssignedTo-->
<FieldRef ID="{1982e408-0f94-4149-8349-16f301d89134}" Hidden="TRUE"/>
<!--Priority-->
<FieldRef ID="{a8eb573e-9e11-481a-a8c9-1104a54b2fbd}" Hidden="TRUE" />

<!--Title-->
<FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Required="TRUE" />
<!--LinkTitle-->
<FieldRef ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" />
<!--LinkTitleNoMenu-->
<FieldRef ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" />

<!--DueDate-->
<FieldRef ID="{cd21b4c2-6841-4f9e-a23a-738a65f99889}" DisplayName="End of Task" Required="TRUE" />
<!--StartDate-->
<FieldRef ID="{64cd368d-2f95-4bfc-a1f9-8d4324ecb007}" DisplayName="Start of Task" Required="TRUE" />

<!--Checkmark-->
<FieldRef ID="{ebf1c037-47eb-4355-998d-47ce9f2cc047}" />
<!--Body-->
<FieldRef ID="{7662cd2c-f069-4dba-9e35-082cf976e170}" />
<!--Predecessors-->
<FieldRef ID="{c3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc6f}" />
<!--RelatedItems-->
<FieldRef ID="{d2a04afc-9a05-48c8-a7fa-fa98f9496141}" />
<!--Status-->
<FieldRef ID="{c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76}" />

<!--ParentID-->
<RemoveFieldRef ID="{fd447db5-3908-4b47-8f8c-a5895ed0aa6a}" />
```

The PreviouslyAssignedTo is Hidden because of the hidden AssignedTo.
If i dont remove ParentID, the Feature wont activate (throws an error)! Anywho, with the field removed the feature will activate but the List throws an Error. Im puzzled.

The List is a simple Tasklist, with the contenttype above added (standard task removed) and the type set to 171 for Tasklist. I added the List with the Visual Studio Wizard and changed the content Type with the Wizard, then just went to the xml and changed the type.

This is the Error Message:

```
HierarchyParentKeyColumnName 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: HierarchyParentKeyColumnName

Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 
[ArgumentException: HierarchyParentKeyColumnName]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.GridSerializer.EnableReservedHierarchy() +35354306
   Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.SPGridSerializerGenerator.GenerateGridSerializer() +718
   Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.SPGridSerializerGenerator.CreateGridSerializer() +257
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.EnsureJSonObject() +1265
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +377
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartMobileAdapter.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +108
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +12756035
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

If you needed further information just leave a comment. Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to sort your mind by simply formulating your question for stackoverflow;) I tried to solve the error with the ParentID for you guys so that you can focus on the real problem. Turns out the ParentID was the real problem.

I added the Lookup target:

```
<!--ID-->
<FieldRef ID="{1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1}" />
<!--ParentID-->
<FieldRef ID="{fd447db5-3908-4b47-8f8c-a5895ed0aa6a}" />
```

And (more important) changed the "self" parent contentTypes (Task) lookup field definition to an actual list-instance.

```
<Field Type="Lookup" 
       Indexed="TRUE" 
       Name="ParentID" 
       ID="{fd447db5-3908-4b47-8f8c-a5895ed0aa6a}" 
       Hidden="TRUE" 
       Required="FALSE" 
       List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;MyTaskList" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Cascade" 
       ShowField="ID" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Parent_ID;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ParentID"></Field>
```